# Change text align and direction of RadHtmlChart data

Tags: html, asp.net, telerik

I have a chart:

```
<telerik:RadHtmlChart ID="chrtInvestmentAmount"  runat="server" Transitions="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="256px" Skin="Glow" Width="1024px" RenderMode="Auto">
        <PlotArea>
            <Series>
                <telerik:ColumnSeries DataFieldY="InvestmentsAmount" Name="כמות משקיעים"/>
            </Series>
            <XAxis DataLabelsField="Month">
               <TitleAppearance Text="חודש" />
            </XAxis>
            <YAxis>
                <TitleAppearance Text="כמות משקיעים" />
            </YAxis>
        </PlotArea>
    </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
```

Now in my body tag I have set the direction of the page to rtl, and when i do that the whole chart gets messed up, the text gets cut off a little and all in all it just doesent look good:

[image: chart]

for some reason it just gets all messed up. Isn't there some small piece of code which can fix this?

And while im asking, another problem i have is after setting the chart type (bars,lines and so on...) it does not update it and i also notice no line of code is added to the HTML. I dont know if something needs to be added, either way i cant change the chart type. Is there some kind of code which can change the chart type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

RadHtmlChart renders with markup (SVG or VML) so some CSS properties can affect it and break it. To avoid such issues you can have them reset for the charts. For example:

```
<telerik:RadHtmlChart CssClass="resetChart" ID="chrtInvestmentAmount"  runat="server" Transitions="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="256px" Skin="Glow" Width="1024px" RenderMode="Auto" >
```

and something like this in the CSS:

```
.resetChart
{
   direction: ltr;
   float: none;
   text-align: left;
}
```

as for the chart type - this depends on the type of series you add to the chart. In your case you ahve a ColumnSeries, to add a different type of chart you need a different type of series. This does not happen with just a click on the design time wizard, its first page only preselects the types of charts you can add in the other tabs like the **Series tab**: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart-design-time-using-visual-designer.html.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to my question was just putting the charts in a table, and not touching anything with the css and the problem was solved.